# MATLAB - generating vector with sequence of values

Tags: matlab

Given two parameters:

```
n %number of repetitions per value
k %max value to repeat
```

I would like to create a vector of size n*k, which is a concatenation of k vectors of size n, such that the i'th vector contains the value i at each coordinate.

Example:

```
n = 5;
k = 9;
```

Desired result:

```
[1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,9];
```

Is there an elegant way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

quite a few ways to do it:

method 1:

```
A=1:k
repelem(A',n,1)'
```

method 2:

```
A=1:k
kron(A', ones(n,1))'
```

method 3:

```
A=1:k
B=repmat(A, n, 1)
B(:)'
```

method 4:

```
A=1:k
B=ones(n,1)*A
B(:)'
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative method

```
A = reshape(mtimes((1:k).',ones(1,n)).',1,n*k)

A =

  Columns 1 through 22

     1     1     1     1     1     2     2     2     2     2     3     3     3     3     3     4     4     4     4     4     5     5

  Columns 23 through 44

     5     5     5     6     6     6     6     6     7     7     7     7     7     8     8     8     8     8     9     9     9     9

  Column 45

     9
```

It multiplies each element by ones n times

```
>> mtimes((1:k).',ones(1,5)).'

ans =

     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9
     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9
     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9
     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9
     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9
```

and then reshapes the whole matrix to one vector